# $\oint_{\gamma _{r}}\frac{z-5}{(z-a)Sin(\pi z)}$ On the circle of radius 1 centered in $-\frac{1}{2}$.

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis

$$\oint_{\gamma _{r}}\frac{z-5}{(z-a)Sin(\pi z)}$$

On the circle of radius 1 centered in $-\frac{1}{2}$.
$$a\in \mathbb{C}$$
$$a\notin\mathbb{R}$$
I want to use the method of residues.
Considering the instance

$$\left | a+\frac{1}{2} \right |>1$$

In this way the singularity $z=a$  is not contained in the circumference.

The integral should be

$$\oint_{\gamma _{r}}\frac{z-5}{(z-a)Sin(\pi z)}=(Res[f,-1])2i\pi=-\frac{6}{(a+1)\pi}$$

On the textbook the result for $\left | a+\frac{1}{2} \right |>1$ is $$2i\frac{a-5}{a(a-1)}$$

Where is my mistake?
Someone can show me the steps?

Thank you so much!

Comment: If $|a+\frac{1}{2}|<1$, there are two poles $z=-1$ and $z=a$.

Comment: Yes but I'm considering the easier instance

Comment: I think what you did is correct. Maybe your textbook has typos.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\Res}{\textrm{Res}}$I believe I've found a mistake in your calculation, but nevertheless the answer I got doesn't match your reported textbook answer either (but it's pretty close). But for what it's worth, here goes:

You are correct that there is a first-order pole at $z = -1$, but don't forget that there is also a first-order pole at $z = 0$ from $\sin(\pi z)$ which falls in the enclosure of $\gamma_r$. This residue has to be added to the one for $z = -1$. I calculated (and got the computer to verify) that
\begin{align}
\Res(z=0) = \frac{5}{\pi a}
\end{align}
Therefore the new result for the contour integral is:
\begin{align}
\oint_{\gamma_r} \frac{z-5}{(z-a) \sin(\pi z)} \, dz &= 2\pi i \left[\frac{5}{\pi a} - \frac{6}{\pi (a+1)} \right] \\
&= 2i \left( \frac{5}{a} - \frac{6}{a+1} \right) \\
&= 2i \left[ \frac{5-a}{a(a+1)} \right]
\end{align}
which is pretty close to your reported answer, except that $a$ and $5$ are swapped and I have $(a+1)$ instead of $(a-1)$.

**UPDATE:** Thanks to Wolfram|Alpha, I integrated brute-force your contour integral for $a = i$ and got $4-6i$ as the result. This matches with my derived formula, but not with the textbook answer you gave (which evaluates to $6+4i$). So unless I overlooked something, it looks like the book is wrong!

Comment: What happens when $a=0$ or $a=-1$?

Comment: Looks like $a = 0 \implies -10 i$, and $a = -1 \implies -12 i$. At least that's what Wolfram spits out. Haven't tried to compute it myself.